# JUnit test, Unrooted Tests: initializationError

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit

So I edited the name of a JUnit test and now it wont work. Instead I get Unrooted Tests: initializationError.

This is a simple test. Infact it is a test for JUnit tests as I am just starting to use it.

```
@Test
public void testRun()
    String s = null;
    assertNull(s);

}
```

and all i did was change it to testRun2(). Also when I run the file not the individual test, it still runs the old testRun(), not testRun2().

My project has Maven not sure if that is a factor. And I have updated the project

Comment: can you post whole test class?

Comment: I bet you try to run it via junit view. This view still holds the old test method name. Just right click on the class  in the package explorer and debug as junit. Then the view will be refreshed and your test will be executed

Answer (score 4):

So it turned out that I needed to rebuild using Maven to update the classes. Now it works fine and I can add/modify test cases.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not using Maven, but Project → Clean… worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i changed the method name and it didn't update it automatically, so the above solution of Project> Clean worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way this error would occur is forgetting the Test annotation.  Encountered when right click method name in Eclipse and Run As -> Junit Test.